# select object where first child id is not a certain value

Tags: jquery, html

ok guyz, got one more question for you.
i need to select only the first div ( where first child != 'you' )
how can i acheive that?

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <div id="me"><img src=""></div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div id="you"></div>
</div>
```

what i mean is something like:

`$('#test:first-child[id] != value');`

well , that is what i need in theory, since i dont think the above line will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yourElement = $(".test").not(":has(>#you:first-child)");
var allImages = yourElement.find("img");
```

translation: select an element which has class "test" and doesn't have a direct child (">") with the id of "you" which is the first element!

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/y3RPD/3/

Comment: This is the opposite of what he wants i think! :)

Comment: can i complicate it a bit and add that i want all images ?

Comment: you can do anything in jquery, images where? please show it in your html please

Comment: all images under the selected div ( since .test was selected , then all images under it )